# Running a bat file in ConEmu opens multiple command windows

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I install ConEmu to run a specific BAT File which should run multiple commands in a command prompt, the problem is that instead of these new command prompts windows being open, I wish that those windows will be open as tabs in Con Emu.

I check a few articles and add this command in Settings, integrations:

```
/single /cmd -cur_console:n
```

But still opens like 17 Command Windows instead of having 17 tabs which the Batch file should open.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a direct answer without knowing what commands are in your script, but in general, you can prevent ConEmu from opening a new terminal and instead cause it to open a new tab with the argument `-new_console`

So for example, if I wanted to open multiple ssh connections, I could do

```
putty host1 -new_console
putty host2 -new_console
putty host3 -new_console
```